# Keep webmethod output cache until refreshed

Tags: asp.net, caching, asmx, webmethod

I have a ASP.NET page with a timer based script calling a WebMethod on the server.

Here is the script on the aspx:

```
function AutoRefreshPage() {

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: pageUrl + "/GetSomeData",
        data: JSON.stringify({ 
        par1: 'a',
        par2: 'b',
        par3: 'c'
        }),
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (response) {
            var objMain = $.parseJSON(response.d);

            // Update data on page...

            // Re-trig method in 30 sec
            setTimeout(AutoRefreshPage, 30000);



        }, 
        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {

            console.log("Error");

            // Re-trig method in 30 sec
            setTimeout(AutoRefreshPage, 30000);

        }
    });

}
```

Here is the webmethod:

```
namespace MyNameSpace
{
    [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [ScriptService]
    [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
    public class AjaxServiceProxy : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {


        [WebMethod(EnableSession = true, CacheDuration = 120)]
        [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
        public string GetSomeData(string par1, string par2, string par3)
        {
            JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();

            // Read from DB (takes abour 10 sec)
            var reply = GetSomeDataFromDB(par1,par2,par3);

            return serializer.Serialize(reply);

        }

    }
}
```

It guess the caching works as it is supposed... At the first call to GetSomeData the DB is hit and data is fetched and saved in cache. Any further calls (with same parameter values) returns the cached data. When the cacheduration of 120 sec expires, the cache is cleared and data is read from DB again. Now to my problem - when the number of calling clients increase (each having their timer based refresh) it is very likely that there are several calls to GetSomeData AFTER the cache has expired but BEFORE the cache has been refreshed. The result will many calls to the DB - all reading the same data. And that was what I really wanted to avoid in the first Place - using cached output! Is there any elegant way to avoid this time-gap of no-valid-cache?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I have the same questions.

Comment: It will not work if  type: "POST" in ajax,. Cache will work only having  type: "get" in your ajax request,